# Custom Form in WordPress Page Won't Submit/Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I had a normal site that I built with custom HTML/CSS/JS. I changed the site to become a WordPress site (and made my custom html/css/js into a custom WordPress theme). I had a contact form on the homepage of the site, which broke when I made the change to WordPress.

When the form was functioning, it would refresh the page and bring the user back down to the form (using the anchor id=contactphilly) and then the user would see a message confirming their email was sent.

I did a LOT of Googling and I think it has something to do with the "action" option in the form, but no matter what I try changing it to, it doesn't work. I tried the following for the action value:

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#contactphilly
#contactphilly
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

None of them worked.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'WebKeep.com'; 
        $to = 'info@webkeepteam.com'; 
        $subjectemail = 'Message from WebKeepTeam.com Contact Form ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Subject: $subject\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
          $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
      $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
  if (mail ($to, $subjectemail, $body, $from)) {
    $result='<div>Thank You! We will respond shortly.</div>';
  } else {
    $result='<div>Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
  }
}
}
?>
```

and

```
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="#contactphilly">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>" class="form-control transparent-input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  </fieldset>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"  class="form-control transparent-input" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  </fieldset>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control transparent-input"  value="<?php echo $subject;?>" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
  </fieldset>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control  transparent-input" id="message"  value="<?php echo $message;?>" name="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
  </fieldset>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-index pull-right">
</div>
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Why you are not using init action for same? Are you new to wordpress?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is your form not submitting *or* is it simply not scrolling back to the anchor when it has completed? I also suggest that you look up how you develop forms for Wordpress or use an existing plugin - simply pasting in your old html form won't work as Wordpress will ignore any posted variables it doesn't recognise (i.e. those in your form).

Comment: @FluffyKitten it redirects to a 404 error page. I might just give up and use a plugin - I thought it would be easier to modify what I already had but maybe not. I'm trying to do something like what this person did, but within a page instead of on its own page. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/ And that person uses <?php the_permalink(); ?> for the action, which I did try by itself and it did not work.

Comment: <?php the_permalink(); ?> *is* the same page. What happened when you used it?

Comment: @FluffyKitten when I use <?php the_permalink(); ?>, it displays a 404 error page. The URL is the homepage though (mywebsite.com). I've also tried making a separate page template for the homepage instead of using front-page.php since another Stack Overflow thread suggested that, but that didn't work either. I'm baffled I don't know why all of these redirect to a 404 page. Every solution I've tried has gone to a 404 page.

Comment: Have you confirmed that <?php the_permalink(); ?> is the url you expect?What url is being displayed in the source of the form?

Comment: @FluffyKitten well sort-of. In the original form (the working one before I migrated to WordPress), the URL that showed when the page refreshed was www.mysite.com#contactphilly so that it brought it down to the part of the page where the form was and the person could see the success message for submitting the form. Now, when I use <?php the_permalink(); ?> it just goes to www.mysite.com which is what I'd expect, but I guess not ideal since I'd like it to scroll down to the #contactphilly ID/anchor where the form is.

Comment: So it is actually submitting and displaying the homepage? I thought you were getting a 404 error?

Comment: @FluffyKitten It IS showing a 404 error, that's the weird thing! It re-directs to the homepage as the URL but shows a 404 error on the page. Here's the link if you want to try it yourself: http://www.webkeepteam.com/

Comment: I took a look at your form, and I notice that some of your inputs have names that are reserved in WP e.g. `name` (https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars). Its possible that WP is intercepting the this value and trying to match it against its rewrite rules and not finding a match. Even if this isn't the problem, its always best practice to use unique names, ids etc to prevent clashed with other code and plugins. Try changing those and see if it helps.

Comment: @FluffyKitten okay great news we are making progress! I changed all the variable names, and now it's reloading the homepage instead of going to 404. The form still doesn't work or send an email though.

Comment: Good news indeed! In that case, I think the problem is to do with passing values in WP. I am really doubting the validity of the example you linked to - we've already identified one major problem with it, and it treats the post values as if it was a normal HTML/php form even though its my understanding that you must register your variables with WP in order to be able to pass them. I'm not in a position right now to explain what you need to do in detail, but I'll come back later - hope thats ok!

Comment: @FluffyKitten yeah that's fine I might just give in and try one of the plugins, and apply my custom CSS to it for now. I'll keep checking back here and let everyone know if anything works.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I found a solution, see what I posted below. Thank you for your help/efforts!

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question! I completely forgot about this bit of code on GitHub: https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server I used it elsewhere on the site and it worked, and it also works beautifully for forms within pages too!